# Check URL for numbers using php

Tags: php, regex, validation, joomla

i'm trying to check if the url on my website contains numbers and if they do add a code to change robots text to noindex nofollow. this is what i have but doesn't seem to work.

```
$urlMatch = $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'];
if ( preg_match('^[0-9+]+$', $urlMatch) ) {
$document = JFactory::getDocument();
$document->setMetaData('robots', "noindex,nofollow");
exit();
}
```

here is an example of a url i'm trying to validate: http://staging.clet.edu.au/online-study/31-course

but nothing seem to be happening... did i miss anything?

Comment: Can you check and post your PHP error log?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your current regex expects one or more digits and ONLY digits.  You simply need to remove the beginning `^` and end `$` anchors in your regex.  There is also no reason to do one or more `+` in this context.

```
$pattern = '/[0-9]/';
if (preg_match($pattern, $urlMatch)) {
...
}
```